# Центрирование блока при изменении ширины

Tags: html, css, float

Есть вёрстка на float. Посты будут добавляться. При нечётном количестве постов кнопка ORDER должна оставаться там где находится сейчас. При чётном кол-ве постов кнопка должна центрироваться снизу по центру по всей ширине.

Подскажите как решить такую задачу.

```css
.all__post {
    width: 750px;
}
  .post__list {
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 0;
  }
.post__item:nth-child(odd) {
    margin-right: 26px;
}

.post__item {
    width: 350px;
    font-family: "Open Sans", serif;
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 57px;
    float: left;
    cursor: pointer;
    outline: none;
}

.post__item-img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #89c39b;
}

.post__item-h {
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    font-size: 24px;
    color: #1a1a1a;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
}
.post__item-span {
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #1a1a1a;
}

.button {
    text-align: center;
    height: 200px;
   position: relative;
}

.button__link {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 30px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 250px;
    height: 70px;
    background-color: #8c5d79;
    color: #1a1a1a;
    line-height: 70px;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 5px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -125px;
}
```

```html
<div class="all__post">
                <ul class="post__list clearfix">
                    <li tabindex="0" class="post__item">
                        
                            <div class="post__item-img"></div>
                            <h2 class="post__item-h">Heading Heading HeadingHeading</h2>
                            <span class="post__item-span">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Magni, magnam! Vel illo sint repellat
                                soluta, et animi ullam porro iusto quisquam pariatur laboriosam odio eligendi eum, vitae
                                ducimus error minima!Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Magni, magnam!Lorem
                                ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Magni, magnam!
                            </span>
                        
                    </li>
                    <li tabindex="0" class="post__item">
                          
                        <div class="post__item-img"></div>
                        <h2 class="post__item-h">Heading</h2>
                        <span class="post__item-span">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Magni, magnam! Vel illo sint repellat soluta,
                            et animi ullam porro iusto quisquam pariatur laboriosam odio eligendi eum, vitae ducimus error
                            minima! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Magni, magnam! Vel illo sint
                            repellat soluta, et animi ullam porro iusto quisquam pariatur laboriosam odio eligendi eum, vitae
                            ducimus error minima! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Magni, magnam!
                            Vel illo sint repellat soluta, et animi ullam porro iusto quisquam pariatur laboriosam odio eligendi
                            eum, vitae ducimus error minima!
                        </span>
                      
                    </li>
                    <li tabindex="0" class="post__item">
                            
                        <div class="post__item-img post__item-img__active"></div>
                        <h2 class="post__item-h">Heading</h2>
                        <span class="post__item-span">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Magni, magnam! Vel illo sint repellat soluta,
                            et animi ullam porro iusto quisquam pariatur laboriosam odio eligendi eum, vitae ducimus error
                            minima! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Magni, magnam! Vel illo sint
                            repellat soluta, et animi ullam porro iusto quisquam pariatur laboriosam odio eligendi eum, vitae
                            ducimus error minima! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Magni, magnam!
                            Vel illo sint repellat soluta, et animi ullam porro iusto quisquam pariatur laboriosam odio eligendi
                            eum, vitae ducimus error minima!
                        </span>
                        
                    </li>
                  
                    <li class="post__item">

                        <div class="button">
                            <a href="" class="button__link">Order</a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
  </ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавьте класс для `li` с кнопкой и стили

```
/*btn-order*/

.btn-order:not(:nth-child(even)) {
  float: none;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  clear: both;
}
```

```css
.all__post {
  width: 750px;
}

.post__list {
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 0;
}

.post__item:nth-child(odd) {
  margin-right: 26px;
}

.post__item {
  width: 350px;
  font-family: "Open Sans", serif;
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 57px;
  float: left;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
}

.post__item-img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #89c39b;
}

.post__item-h {
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #1a1a1a;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
}

.post__item-span {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #1a1a1a;
}

.button {
  text-align: center;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
}

.button__link {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 250px;
  height: 70px;
  background-color: #8c5d79;
  color: #1a1a1a;
  line-height: 70px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -125px;
}


/*btn-order*/

.btn-order:not(:nth-child(even)) {
  float: none;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="all__post">
  <ul class="post__list clearfix">
    <li tabindex="0" class="post__item">

      <div class="post__item-img"></div>
      <h2 class="post__item-h">Heading Heading HeadingHeading</h2>
      <span class="post__item-span">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Magni, magnam! Vel illo sint repellat
                                soluta, et animi ullam porro iusto quisquam pariatur laboriosam odio eligendi eum, vitae
                                ducimus error minima!Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Magni, magnam!Lorem
                                ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Magni, magnam!
                            </span>

    </li>
        <li tabindex="0" class="post__item">

      <div class="post__item-img"></div>
      <h2 class="post__item-h">Heading Heading HeadingHeading</h2>
      <span class="post__item-span">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Magni, magnam! Vel illo sint repellat
                                soluta, et animi ullam porro iusto quisquam pariatur laboriosam odio eligendi eum, vitae
                                ducimus error minima!Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Magni, magnam!Lorem
                                ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Magni, magnam!
                            </span>

    </li>
    <li tabindex="0" class="post__item">

      <div class="post__item-img"></div>
      <h2 class="post__item-h">Heading</h2>
      <span class="post__item-span">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Magni, magnam! Vel illo sint repellat soluta,
                            et animi ullam porro iusto quisquam pariatur laboriosam odio eligendi eum, vitae ducimus error
                            minima! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Magni, magnam! Vel illo sint
                            repellat soluta, et animi ullam porro iusto quisquam pariatur laboriosam odio eligendi eum, vitae
                            ducimus error minima! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Magni, magnam!
                            Vel illo sint repellat soluta, et animi ullam porro iusto quisquam pariatur laboriosam odio eligendi
                            eum, vitae ducimus error minima!
                        </span>

    </li>
    <li tabindex="0" class="post__item">

      <div class="post__item-img post__item-img__active"></div>
      <h2 class="post__item-h">Heading</h2>
      <span class="post__item-span">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Magni, magnam! Vel illo sint repellat soluta,
                            et animi ullam porro iusto quisquam pariatur laboriosam odio eligendi eum, vitae ducimus error
                            minima! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Magni, magnam! Vel illo sint
                            repellat soluta, et animi ullam porro iusto quisquam pariatur laboriosam odio eligendi eum, vitae
                            ducimus error minima! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Magni, magnam!
                            Vel illo sint repellat soluta, et animi ullam porro iusto quisquam pariatur laboriosam odio eligendi
                            eum, vitae ducimus error minima!
                        </span>

    </li>

    <li class="post__item btn-order">

      <div class="button">
        <a href="" class="button__link">Order</a>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Не знал про :not.

Comment: галочка слева от овета